# AES Negative bytes

Tags: c#, java, aes

The following is an extract from using AES encryption in Java:

```
  encryptedData =   encryptCipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes());
```

The following is an extract in c#

```
 DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(encrypted, myAes.Key, myAes.IV);
```

Both use a byte array one to encrypt the other to decrypt, the encryption in Java encrypts producing some negative values stored in a byte array.

C# uses a byte array to decrypt but a byte in C# is defined as only containing the numbers from 0..255 - Java defines its Byte type as -128 to 127.

Therefore, I cannot send encrypted data to the remote application which is written in C# because it cannot decrypt using the byte array that has been sent from the Java aplication.

Has anyone come up with a solution that would allow me to tell java not to produce negative numbers when encrypting?

The code is from Micrsoft, the MemoryStream requires the byte[] to create the stream for the crypto code...
As mentioned or not, I replaced byte[] with sbyte but to no avail as MemoryStream requires byte[]

```
static string DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(sbyte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        // Check arguments. 
        if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");

        // Declare the string used to hold 
        // the decrypted text. 
        string plaintext = null;

        // Create an Aes object 
        // with the specified key and IV. 
        using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
        {
            aesAlg.Key = Key;
            aesAlg.IV = IV;

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for decryption. 
            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream((byte)cipherText))
            {
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                    {


                        // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                        // and place them in a string.
                        plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        return plaintext;


    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Java's bytes are signed, C# bytes are unsigned (there's also an `sbyte` type in C#, that no one uses, which works like Java's bytes).

It doesn't matter. They are different in some regards, namely

- when converted to `int`, C#'s bytes will be zero-extended, Java's bytes will be sign-extended (which is why you almost always see `& 0xFF` when bytes are used in Java).
- when converted to string, Java's bytes will have their 128 - 255 range mapped to -128 - -1. Just ignore that.

The actual value of those bytes (that is, their bit-pattern) is what actually matters, a byte that is 0xAA will be 0xAA regardless of whether you interpret it as 170 (as in C#) or -86 (as in Java). It's the same thing, just a different way to print it as string.

---

`new MemoryStream((byte)cipherText))` definitely doesn't do the right thing (or anything, it shouldn't even compile). The related `new MemoryStream((byte[])cipherText))` wouldn't work either, you can't cast between primitive arrays like that. `cipherText` should just be a `byte[]` to begin with.

Comment: I see what your saying but, when the byte data is sent to the c# application, the data that's passed into the encryption function (which comes from c# library) throws an exception complaining that it expects an unsigned byte array? Grateful for your help et-al

Comment: @Perry that doesn't really make sense, there is no way to give it anything else - it takes a byte array, by definition it's unsigned

Comment: Harold, Java and Objective-C use signed byte arrays. So when I call the respective encrypting functions for these lanaguages, they return a signed byte array, whereas C# uses unsigned byte arrays and likewise the functions to encrypt and decrypt using C# use unsigned byte arrays - I have tried all 3 and that's what I have found. I can send and received encrypted data between IOS and Java and then decrypt, but calling the methods on C# to decrypt is where it is problematic.

Comment: @Perry can you post some more code? For the C# side. I still don't see how this could possibly go wrong.

Comment: It seems I can't past the whoe thing so this is the header to ti call: static string DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV) // the call within this is to MemoryStream which takes the byte[]. Within this function it calls MemoryStream which create a stream for the crypto code using the byte[]. The encrypted data is : { 89,  -62,  -75, 88, 113, 93,  -57, 47,  -18, 14,  -26,  -57, 49, 13, -73, -42, -103, 109, -75, 22, 62, -117, -33, 81, 56, -3, -124, -13, -128, 103, -27, 42 };

Comment: @Perry you can edit it into your question. Don't use sbytes in C#.

Answer (score 1):

You could turn it into a string with some encoding, like:

```
encryptedData =   encryptCipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes());
String s = new String(encryptedData, "Base-64");
```

Using the same standardized encoding, both C# and Java should be able to reconstruct each others encrypted data from that string.

Comment: Nice example, answer is also a good fit. I also thought about standardized encoding.

Comment: In brief, if the encryption produces negative values the decryption has to take those negative values to convert back to normal text. The default decription MemoryStream used in C# takes unsigned bytes, which means you cannot just reverse the two's compliment on the negative values doing so changes the end result. The only way I have found so far, is to not use Microsoft's default Crypto - instead opt for a 3rd parties decryption method that takes negative values. Thank you anyway.