# HMACSHA256.ComputeHash(byte[] arr, int , int ) is not matching the output of Java Mac.doFinal(byte[] arr)

Tags: java, c#

**Java Code**

```
private void GenerateSignInfo(byte[] buffer) throws InvalidKeyException, UnsupportedEncodingException, ShortBufferException, IllegalStateException {

    String Key="HelloWorld";
    byte[] keyData = Base64.getDecoder().decode(Key);

    Mac sha256_HMAC = null;
    try {
        sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(keyData, "HmacSHA256");
    sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);

    byte[]hashmessage=sha256_HMAC.doFinal(buffer);
    System.out.println("Hash Message generated from doFinal");
    for (byte b : hashmessage) {
        System.out.print(b);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

**C# Code**

```
private void GenerateSignInfo(byte[] buffer)
{

        byte[] key_data = Convert.FromBase64String("HelloWorld");

        HMACSHA256 hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(key_data);

        byte[] hashMessage = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(buffer ,0, 48);

        Console.WriteLine("hash message computed from HMACSHA256");
        foreach (byte b in hashMessage)
        {
            Console.Write(b + " ");`enter code here`
        }           
}
```

Comment: Please provide sample outputs.

Comment: Having finally put together my own test for your question, it's down to bytes in Java being signed, and as [harold says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23079349/3181933), you can fix the Java code by using `b & 0xFF`.

Comment: I have handle the negative bytes in java by adding 256 but the function HMACSHA256. ComputeHash(byte []arr, int offset, int counter) is generating different output from Java method Mac.doFinal(byte []arr) . I can't change C# code, I just need java variant of computehash function in c# having three parameters and both method should produce same output.

Comment: Well, feel free to add samples of that to your question in the form of an edit. When I tested it with the fix from the other question, both produced the exact same output.

Comment: John you have used which variant in C# ?

Comment: I will share you the sample output

Comment: I used your C# code verbatim and simply applied the fix I suggested to the Java version.